# Oracle virtualbox networking via software router on host

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have installed Oracle Virtual Box and have two virtual machines running in it. Both have Windows 7 64 bit installed.

I need internet connection on both as well as I need them to be on the Homegroup network.

- With the `NAT` selection for Network in VirtualBox, the machine gets an internet connection from host via software interface, but the host can't see the virtual machine on network.
- With the `NAT Network` selection, one VM can see other VMs on network, but the host still can't see the VM.
- The situation I want is possible right now with the selection of `Bridged Adapter` but I believe that works directly through the physical router with which the host is itself connected which I don't want, because I need to debug a .net code remotely and it becomes bit slow. I need this same situation i.e. Internet Connection, Homegroup network via the Software interface.
- With the `Host Only Adapter` selection, I can make available Homegroup network to Virtual Machines and every machine can see everyone else but it can't provide Internet Connection to the Virtual machines.

Is there any way, that I can provide a network to the Virtual Machines via Software Interface and they are able to access Internet Connection from host and at the same time, the machines including Host are able to see each other on the network?

I need a the Virtual Machines connected to host via a Homegroup network and not public Network. The host itself will need to have another public network with which it will access internet. But when I configure two networks on host, one public and one homegroup, the homegroup doesn't work properly and I have read on internet that for homegroup you should have only one network for it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Create two network adapters on each guest. Set the first one to NAT and the second to a host-only network. Windows should initialize both interfaces. The guests will be able to access the Internet through the NAT interface, and the host and guests will be able to communicate with each other through the host-only network.

Comment: I have tried that already, but if both of these adapters are enabled at once, internet works, but network resolution sometimes takes very long time, sometimes doesn't work and keep on finding the computers on network without any results. When I disable NAT, the network discovery works instantly and I can see the network computers instantly. But enabling NAT cause the problem again.